# argument type 'T.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Comparable'

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to create a small class in swift but getting the following error argument type `T.Type` does not conform to expected type `Comparable`

Can someone help?

```
struct BST<T: Comparable> {
  let root: Node<T>?
  var count = 0

  init<T:Comparable>(data: T) {
    self.root = Node(data  : T) //Error Occurs in this line
  }
}//end class BST
```

Here is code of `Node` class.

```
class Node<T: Comparable> {
  let data: T
  var left: Node?
  var right: Node?

  init(data: T) {
    self.data = data
  } //end init

} //end class node

func == <T> (lhs: Node<T>, rhs: Node<T>) -> Bool {
  return lhs.data == rhs.data
} //end ==

func < <T> (lhs: Node<T>, rhs: Node<T>) -> Bool {
  if(rhs.data > lhs.data) {
    return true
  }
  return false
} //end fun <
```

Comment: Add the code of `Node`?

Comment: Can you add you Node struct code too?

Comment: full code here  https://ideone.com/paWE8j 
for some reason, not able to add code to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `data` in the initializer not `T`. and also there is no need to make initialize generic.

Change your code:

```
struct BST<T: Comparable> {
    let root: Node<T>?
    var count = 0

    init(data: T) {
        self.root = Node(data: data)
    }

}//end class BST
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.root = Node(data  : T) //Error Occurs in this line
```

You are trying to initialize a `Node` with the type, instead of the value.

Try

```
self.root = Node(data  : data)
```